# What do you call it when you raise your humerus behind yourself?

Tags: terminology

When you raise your humerus in front of yourself, it's called shoulder flexion, right? What do you call it when you raise your humerus behind yourself? Is it hyperextension? Or "posterior flexion"?

Comment: These are technical terms not used in ordinary conversation, but when I looked up _shoulder flexion_ I found [this](https://www.healthline.com/health/shoulder-range-of-motion#What-is-normal-shoulder-range-of-motion?).

Comment: Try asking about muscle exercises on [fitness.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you call it when you raise your humerus behind yourself?

Extension.

See the pic on this [webpage](https://orthofixar.com/special-test/shoulder-range-of-motion/).

Comment: That's a great link, thank you! 